# What is the purpose of the tables finishing by '_nd' on ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have to work on a ClickHouse cluster, but I don't understand well the purpose of the double table.

For example :

[image: some clickhouse db]

For each table I have a clone with the suffix '_nd', I know that the difference is about the replication the data over the cluster. The one without '_nd' is local to the server and the other one is for the cluster.

But why is there those 'duplicates' ?
Is it for performance reason ? What will be the impact for me in my code ?

Comment: it looks like one table is [Distributed](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed/) when the second one - [Replicated](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replication/). Check the engines for both tables.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation explain what they does, but no explanation about the 'why' is there two different one, It could be shadowed, but it's visible. I'm totally neophyte in this world.

Comment: look at this article [Circular Replication Cluster Topology in ClickHouse](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/5/10/circular-replication-cluster-topology-in-clickhouse) where the essence of thе Distributed & Replicated engines is explained using an example circular-topology.

Comment: + [Introduction to the Mysteries of ClickHouse Replication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DlQ6sVKQaA)

Comment: It's great lectures, thanks a lot !